# Xdotool to move terminal window to new Workspace / Desktop

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, xdotool

I'm looking for a way to **move a terminal window** running the following command. The terminal-window should be sent to workspace 2 after 30 seconds.

The following code **didn't** work:

```
sleep 30 && xdotool getactivewindow set_desktop_for_window 2
```

This command will move ANY window that currently has the focus. It is the terminal window running the command which I want to move, though.

Please note that I'm using GNOME-Terminal.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `wmctrl`.

Comment: @Quasímodo Oh, I understand. The window that should be moved is terminal 2. (the one running `sleep 30 && xdotool getactivewindow set_desktop_for_window 2` --- Use case is that I want the window to popup as a reminder e. g. a tea timer on workspace 2 where I'm working.

Comment: Thanks! Can you also mention your terminal in the question? Did you know `gxmessage` has an option for popping up in all workspaces? It would be `sleep 30 && gxmessage -sticky "message"`.

Comment: @Quasímodo thank you sir! That solved my use case. I'll leave this question as a ressource for user looking for a xdotool solution. Would be interested in combination with lines of code displaying timer information e. g. `termdown`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xterm and Kitty, which set the window ID variable,

```
xdotool set_desktop_for_window "$WINDOWID" 2
```

Other terminals:

```
id=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
#Sleep...
xdotool set_desktop_for_window "$id" 2
```

> Use case is that I want the window to popup as a reminder on workspace 2 where I'm working.

Gxmessage's `-sticky` option maps the window to all workspaces.

```
gxmessage -sticky "Reminder"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked nicely. I'm using it as a chained command to fire off in bash
`id=$(xdotool getactivewindow); sleep 30; xdotool set_desktop_for_window "$id" 2`